# Quick search on filename

Tags: android-studio

How can I quick search a class file or entire resource file in android studio?

Eclipse short cuts are

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for all resource files (include `.java` file)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for all Java class in classpath

Currently, I have changed keymap settings to `Eclipse` so that I am able to use same short cuts in Android Studio. However, I need to know what is the default shortcut keys in Android Studio.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

deniz, you can search everywhere with <kbd>Double **Shift**</kbd>.

It looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 48):

To search by file name use the following shortcut keys

On Mac: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

On Windows / Linux: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

To search only recent files:

`ctrl+E`

To search all files:

`shift + shift`

Answer (score 7):

**Android Studio Find Files**

Mac: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌃ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> 
Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>

[[More shortcuts]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776553/4770877)

Answer (score 3):

You can use search button or double shift

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Navigate Menu->File` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

You Can Also use for All files Search(Double tap Shift):

```
 Shift+Shift
```

For Viewing Recent Files Search:

```
ctl+E
```