# Android Studio. Class search stopped working. (Navigate -> Class...)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have migrated to AndroidStudio recently from Eclipse. Have mapping of the hotkeys eclipse-style. The Class Search (Ctrl+Shift+T) worked just fine. Until today. For my main project it doesn't show any classes. Reopening/restarting didn't help. When I open another project it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

i think you use double shift for search any class in your project or else visit this 
[  [1]: [Quick search on filename Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419684/quick-search-on-filename-android-studio][1])

i hope this will help you

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment but this is not the case. Even including non-project files doesn't help