# Project search is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used Android Studio project search for a long time now, but it stopped working recently. It always issues an error message stating "Cannot preview regular expression search yet"

How do fix this ?

[image: screenshot - Android Studio - search]

Comment: just go to your file menu and do invalidate caches\restart

Comment: Tried that several times but does not resolve the problem. This issue is persistent for about a week now.

Answer (score 3):

Search preview for regular expressions is not supported in the version of Android Studio being used. Uncheck "Regular expression" under options for the search to work normally.

Upon updating to Android Studio 2016, it works even with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use search button or double shift its work for android studio 2.3.3 never check android studio 3.0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305871/4549220