# How can I locate a file at folder tree structure quickly in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I hope to locate a file at left folder tree structure in Android Studio just like Image 1.

At present I have to see the file navigation bar first, then expand the left folder tree structure to find it.

You know that the file navigation bar is very long normally, and the folder tree is very complex.

BTW, I can't find the shortcut function from the right-click menu.

**Image 1**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try enabling the "Autoscroll from source" setting in the Project sidebar:

Click the "**Gear**"[⚙️] icon in the "**Project**" sidebar, then select "**Autoscroll from Source**". This will make it so that when you select a file it's a location in the project tree is highlighted.

[image: Autoscroll from Source]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since at least Android Studio Dolphin, something like a search or filter box is not available, and there is no right-click option.

The menu alternative is unrelated to the document tree and hidden in the Navigate menu or Ctrl+Shift+n. There is an alternative keyboard not mappable to any alternative, "press shift twice". This is very unusual in software UX.

See accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419684/quick-search-on-filename).

Answer (score -2):

if i understood correctly you want to search for a file from the tree view.
In Android studio you can click on the tree view and start typing the name of the file and it will highlight files based upon your search query.

I am searching for "manifest" :

[image]" here:

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Alternatively outdated.